# How do I calculate percentage for my subgroup in R using group by and summarize

Tags: r

```
| Cohort | Diabetes Type| Smoking Status
| 1      | 2            | Current
| 0      | 1            | Former
| 1      | 2            | Unknown
| 1      | 2            | Former
| 0      | 1            | Current
| 1      | 2            | Current
```

The table name is Smoking_full

I tried the following code :

```
Smoking_adhere <-Smoking_full %>%
group_by(Cohort) %>%
summarise(nSmoking = sum(!is.na(SmokingStatus)),
#perSmoking = paste0(round(SmokingStatus/sum(SmokingStatus)*100, 2), "%"),
#(pSmoking = 100 * n() / nrow(SmokingStatus)),
) %>%
```

I am able to classify it as totaln, but I am not able to get it as percentage.

I want the tibble to also display percentage of users in each group.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: Just like you use `sum()` to get a count, you can use `mean()` to get a proportion.

Comment: I want to have following expected output 1 )is to get percentage in simple terms: To have something like 60% of smokingstatus come from cohort 0 and 40% come from cohort 1. I do not how to get that percentage 2) I also want to know for cohort 1 how many percentage are current smoker, unknow or former and for cohort 0 how many percentage are current unknow or former?

Comment: You can share sample dataset using `dput()` function to be able to give you what you want

Comment: I should be more specific. Sharon, what is your _specific_ expected output, i.e., what exact values from these 6 rows of data?

Comment: I want to have following expected output 1 )is to get percentage in simple terms: To have something like 60% of smokingstatus come from cohort 0 and 40% come from cohort 1. I do not how to get that percentage 2) I also want to know for cohort 1 how many percentage are current smoker, unknow or former and for cohort 0 how many percentage are current unknow or former? I want the tibble to have 3 columns classifying it as cohort and than calculating it by percentage for each cohort